# In Iphone app need to add text on image like befunnky app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have to add text on image like caption on images ,For that i use

ZDStickerView

I have to add fonts and different colours to caption.As i implemented fonts and colours on caption using ZDStickerView. When i zoom out that image.the colour of image get blurred.i need to create image clear without geting bur when i zoom it..

Code :

```
UILabel  *lb1 = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];

UIimageview *imgview_sign =  [[UIImageview alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,140)];

[imgview_sign addsubview:lbl1];
//add aZDSticker view

ZDStickerView *userResizableView = [[ZDStickerView alloc] initWithFrame:imgview_sign.frame];
userResizableView.tag = 0;
userResizableView.delegate = self;
userResizableView.contentView = imgview_sign;
userResizableView.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview = NO;
[userResizableView showEditingHandles];
[self.view addSubview:userResizableView];

//This code helps me in zooming image in and out at some fixed point using pan gesture.
```

Comment: I am the author of ZDStickerView(https://github.com/zedoul/ZDStickerView) and I did a test with your code. But I failed to reproduce the result, as I do not have the image you used.

Could you let me know your target image? In my case, I used 450 × 359 resolution image in order to prevent "blurred situation", but not sure as I do not know the context yet.